# Heroku can't find some of my rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm new to web development, and I've been working on a simple app for learning purposes.  I've been able to deploy to Heroku from my local machine, but for some reason, the custom classes that I use for some vector images aren't rendering on Heroku.

[This is my page,](https://enigmatic-hollows-2702.herokuapp.com/) and as you can see, there are just squares where there should be different images.  Looking in the inspector, you see the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - https://enigmatic-hollows-2702.herokuapp.com/assets/flaticon.woff

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://enigmatic-hollows-2702.herokuapp.com/assets/flaticon.ttf
```

I have tried recompiling assets, recommitting, and pushing to Heroku, but this error persists.  What's weird is that if I use Heroku Bash and view the Heroku file directory, it looks like the files are there:

[image: directory of Heroku files]

But they are still throwing up that error in the inspector.  I've also got the following set in my production.rb file:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Any idea what could be causing this asset issue? I'm using Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: I'm also using the following in my gemfile:

`group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end`

Comment: Images load for me.  Try a hard refresh, shift+f5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question after reading through [this link.](https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570)  Essentially, I moved the font files out of my CSS directory and into their own fonts directory under the app/assets directory, and then in production.rb added the following line to the Application class:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`

and presto! It worked.  I didn't mess around with @font-face in CSS, since the assets I'm using from flat-icons are built through custom classes used in span or div blocks.